# Blocking Client connection from the Server side, when User types one of the arrow keys

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I need to block a connection from the Server side, based on users who type `up/down/left/right arrow` on the Client side.

I tried one of the following, but it does not work:

```
strcmp( userName, "^[[A" ) == 0
```

I created a socket server which checks a connection for an valid nickname, but when the client types one of the arrows:

```
up arrow    = ^[[A
down arrow  = ^[[B
left arrow  = ^[[D
right arrow = ^[[C
```

On the server side is just ignored and it does not close the client.
Here is a program which illustrate the problem:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PORT 8888
#define MSGLEN 256
#define MAXNAMELENGTH 25

int server_socket = 0;
int client_socket = 0;
struct sockaddr_in address;

void create_sckt  ( void );
void bind_sckt    ( const size_t server_len );
void listen_sckt  ( void );
void accept_sckt  ( size_t server_len );
ssize_t recv_sckt ( char *const userName );
void send_msg ( const int userID, const char *const userName );


int main( void )
{
    size_t server_len              = sizeof( address );
    char userName[ MSGLEN + 1 ]    = { 0 };
    const char *const wrong_name   = "[+]Please type a Valide Name and come back.\n";

    create_sckt ();
    bind_sckt   ( server_len );
    listen_sckt ();

    printf( "Starting Server...\n" );
    while ( 1 )
    {
        accept_sckt( server_len );
        memset( userName, '\0', sizeof(userName ) );
        recv_sckt( userName );
        userName[ strcspn( userName, "\n" ) ] = 0;
        if ( strcmp( userName, "^[[A" ) == 0 && strlen( userName ) > MAXNAMELENGTH )
        {
            send_msg ( client_socket, wrong_name );
            close( client_socket );
            break;
        }else
        {
            char welcome_msg[1024] = { 0 };
            sprintf( welcome_msg, " Welcome %s\n", userName );
            send_msg ( client_socket, welcome_msg );
        }
    }
    close( server_socket );
}

void create_sckt ( void )
{
    server_socket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
    if ( server_socket == -1 )
    {
        printf("socket() failed\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "%s %d\n", strerror(errno), errno);
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
}

void listen_sckt ( void )
{
    int ret = listen( server_socket, 3 );
    if ( ret == -1 )
    {
        printf ( "listen() failed\n" );
        fprintf( stderr, "%s %d\n", strerror( errno ), errno );
        exit   ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
void bind_sckt ( const size_t server_len )
{
    int ret = bind( server_socket, ( struct sockaddr* )&address, ( socklen_t )server_len );
    if (  ret == -1 )
    {
        printf ( "bind() failed\n" );
        fprintf( stderr, "%s %d\n", strerror( errno ), errno);
        exit   ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}

void accept_sckt ( size_t server_len )
{
    client_socket = accept( server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&server_len );
    if ( client_socket == -1 )
    {
        printf ( "accept() failed\n" );
        fprintf( stderr, "%s %d\n", strerror(errno), errno );
        exit   ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}

void send_msg ( const int userID, const char *const userName )
{
    ssize_t ret = send( userID , userName , strlen( userName ) , 0 );
    if ( ret == -1 )
    {
        printf ( "recv() failed\n" );
        fprintf( stderr, "%s %d\n", strerror( errno ), errno );
        exit   ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }else
    {
        printf( "Hello message sent\n" );
    }
}

ssize_t recv_sckt ( char *const userName )
{
    ssize_t ret = recv( client_socket, userName, MSGLEN, 0);
    if ( ret == -1 )
    {
        printf ( "recv() failed\n" );
        fprintf( stderr, "%s %d\n", strerror( errno ), errno );
        exit   ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    return ret;
}
```

How should I block the connection, when on the client side are used one of the `arrow` keys?
On the client side it prints (welcome ):

```
Please enter your name: ^[[A
Connect to Server: 192.168.0.103:8888
You are: 192.168.0.103:42074
 Welcome
```

Comment: `^[` is an ANSI CSI sequences. Read more about them on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). The `^` is non writable character. Use `"\x27["` as the string for comparision.

Comment: I tried that (`strcmp( userName, "\x27[A" ) == 0`)  and it is not working. Still prints `Welcome` msg

Comment: @KamilCuk What good is `"\x27[A"` supposed to do? 0x27 is the apostrophe `'`. A better try would be `"\x1B[A"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I tried examples which was provided in the above Answer and also in one comment and did not work. I found a solution to my problem.

`GCC` seems to allow `\e` but it is not standard:

```
error: non-ISO-standard escape sequence, '\e'|
```

Tryed also with `"\x27[A"` and still no working.

The only thing which worked in this case is `0x1B`:

```
if ( userName[0] == 0x1B )
```

Comment: Then feel free to accept this answer. Indeed escepe sequences start with 0x1B hex value.

Comment: What was the `"\x27[A"` good for? `0x27` is the apostrophe `'`. You should try `"\x1B[A"`. But with your test for `(userName[0] == 0x1B)`, you can define a bunch of subsequent tests, so I think that's a good approach anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Because the first two characters `^[` represent a single escape character.  Try comparing to string `"\e[A"` instead.  And change the logical operator from `&&` to `||`.  You want to fail if it's an arrow **or** it's too long.

Comment: Doing that, I get `error: non-ISO-standard escape sequence, '\e'|` which is not what I need.